# Other thread does not wake up even after notifying and releasing the lock in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-3.9

```
import time
from threading import *
import random

class appointment:
    def patient(self):
        for _ in range(2):
            condition_object.acquire()
            print('patient john waiting for appointment')
            condition_object.notify()
            condition_object.wait() # Thread is in waiting state
            print('patiend john successfully got the appointment')
        condition_object.notify()
        condition_object.release()
        print('patient john is done')

    def doctor(self):
        for _ in range(2):
            print('doctor in chamber')
            condition_object.acquire()
            print('doctor jarry checking the time for appointment')
            time=0
            time=random.randint(1,13)
            print('oppointed time is {} PM'.format(time))
            condition_object.notify()
            print('doctor is going to wait')
            condition_object.wait(1.1)
        print('doctor is about to leave')
        condition_object.release()
        print('doctor is done')
    
condition_object = Condition()
class_obj=appointment()

T1 = Thread(target=class_obj.patient)
T2 = Thread(target=class_obj.doctor)

T1.start()
T2.start()

T1.join()
T2.join()
print("\nEND\n")
```

This a typical consumer producer threading code. And at the end of 2 loops, I expect that when patient thread notifies other thread and releases the lock, the waiting doctor thread would wake up. But the waiting doctor thread is not waking up (even if I set a timer).

The doctor thread wakes up if I use wait() at the end of the patient() function instead of release, but then the patient function isn't waking up after I release the lock from the doctor thread. I'm really confused.

**Why isn't doctor thread waking up after release of lock from the other thread?**

And

**Why is the doctor thread waking up only after wait() is called from the other thread?**

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code the following way and it seems that it works as it should:

```py
from threading import *
import random


class Appointment:
    def __init__(self, cond: Condition):
        self.cond = cond

    def patient(self):
        with self.cond:
            for _ in range(2):
                print('Patient John waiting for appointment')
                self.cond.notify()
                self.cond.wait()  # Thread is in waiting state
                print('Patient John successfully got the appointment')
                self.cond.notify()
        print('Patient John is done')

    def doctor(self):
        print('Doctor in chamber')
        with self.cond:
            for _ in range(2):
                print('Doctor Jarry checking the time for appointment')
                t = random.randint(1, 13)
                print('appointed time is {} PM'.format(t))
                self.cond.notify()
                print('Doctor is going to wait')
                self.cond.wait()
            print('Doctor is about to leave')
        print('Doctor is done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _condition_object = Condition()
    class_obj = Appointment(_condition_object)
    ths = [Thread(target=class_obj.patient), Thread(target=class_obj.doctor)]
    [th.start() for th in ths]
    [th.join() for th in ths]
    print("\nEND\n")
```

Comment: the with clause does the same thing as aquire and release. right?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly yes `with` is more compact version of syntax, it has `acquire` and `release` underthehood.

Comment: So the ig my code wasn't working due to unnecessary calls to the `acquire` method within the loop. Could you make an edit to your answer and include this?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly I guess you had error in indentation after the line ` print('patiend john successfully got the appointment')` in `patient()`. I found your code hard to work with, so rewrote it to more compact form, which allows to make less such mistakes.

Comment: No, I don't think that indentation was the problem. My compiler would have given an error then.

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly it is logical error, no syntax one, no compiler or interpreter gives error in such case.

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly another error which I see is that you try to acquire lock two times in `patient()`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition

> If the lock argument is given and not None, it must be a Lock or RLock
> object, and it is used as the underlying lock.  **Otherwise, a new RLock
> object is created and used as the underlying lock**.

And as stated in https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.RLock

> A reentrant lock must be released by the thread that acquired it.
> Once a thread has acquired a reentrant lock, the same thread may
> acquire it again without blocking; **the thread must release it once for
> each time it has acquired it**

So, the problem with my code was that were more calls to `acquire` the `RLock` than to `release` it. Hence as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67617044/13023201 this answer shows, using a `with` clause with the `Condition` object or calling `acquire` outside the loop solves the problem.